# How can I programmatically connect to a remote database server that requires an SSH tunnel?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm working on an ETL using C# in which extracts data from a remote MySQL database that requires an SSH tunnel to connect.  I currently have it working such that I first create my SSH tunnel manually using PuTTY and then programmaticly connect to the database normally using a MySqlConnection object, etc.

How can I programmatically create the SSH tunnel using C#/.NET?  Are there any libraries for doing this and/or is anything built into the .NET framework itself that would aid me in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create keys so you don't have to use a password for SSH.
2. Do the proper SSH command with the proper arguments(for TCP forwarding)(calling an external EXE such as putty)
3. Use the proper connections settings.
4. Your done!